# hasura/graphql engine always restarting while i user online heroku db

Tags: docker, graphql, restart, hasura

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                   CREATED          STATUS                          PORTS                                       NAMES
9894549e2edd   hasura/graphql-engine:v2.10.1   "/bin/sh -c '\"${HGE_…"   29 seconds ago   Up Less than a second           0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   backend-graphql-engine-1
03af36df02d1   postgres:10                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"    29 seconds ago   Restarting (1) 11 seconds ago                                               backend-postgres-1
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the postgres container logs? I would try with Postgres 14

Answer (score 0):

the error was that by mistake I make the heroku db for metadata and also the db it self , fixed it by making metadata db local postgredb